# invalid types 'double[int]' for array subscript

Tags: array, c++, classes

Eu tenho que fazer uma função FLorentzProton que recebe dois vetores e multiplica eles usando uma outra função ProdutoVetorial (que está em outra classe), depois multiplica o vetor resultante por um número escalar (q). Pelo visto ele não deixa eu multiplicar esse q pelos valores do vetor F. Coloquei os .h e .cc de referência por via da dúvida.

*Mathematics.h*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class Mathematics
{
  float ProdutoVetorial(double B[3], double C[3]);
};
```

*Mathematics.cc*

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Mathematics.h"

float Mathematics::ProdutoVetorial(double B[3], double C[3])
{
    double A[3];
    
    A[0]= (B[1]*C[2] - C[1]*B[2]);
    A[1]= (B[2]*C[0] - C[2]*B[0]);
    A[2]= (B[0]*C[1] - C[0]*B[1]);
    
    return A[3];
}
```

*Physics.h*

```
#include <math.h>

class Physics
{
  float FLorentzProton(double v[3], double B[3]);
};
```

*Physics.cc*

```
#include "Physics.h"

float Physics::FLorentzProton(double v[3], double B[3])
{   
    double q = 1.602*(10^-19);
    double F = float Mathematics->ProdutoVetorial(double v[3], double B[3]);
 
    for(int i=0; i<=2 ;i++) 
    {
        F[i] = q*F[i];
    };
    
    return F[3];
}
```

Comment: Ele também acusa "expected primary-expression before 'float'" na declaração de F e não sei como resolver

Comment: está linha "double F = float Mathematics->ProdutoVetorial(double v[3], double B[3]);"

Comment: o 'float', faz o compilador esperar uma declaração, algo que também não é valido como atribuição, como está... só remova o 'float'

Comment: a parte do "doble v[3], double B[3]", também não faz o menor sentido, invés disto, apenas coloque o nome de variáveis, "v,b", acredito que seja o caso